# initiante matrixes with ranged random numbers in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am looking for a way for initializing a N*N matrix with numbers in range of [-1000,1000] in python, with numpy or any thing else?
I have tried:

```
>>> import numpy as NP

>>> a1 = NP.matrix("4 3 5; 6 7 8; 1 3 13; 7 21 9")
>> a1
matrix([[ 4,  3,  5],
    [ 6,  7,  8],
    [ 1,  3, 13],
    [ 7, 21,  9]])

 >>> a2 = NP.matrix("7 8 15; 5 3 11; 7 4 9; 6 15 4")
>>> a2
matrix([[ 7,  8, 15],
    [ 5,  3, 11],
    [ 7,  4,  9],
    [ 6, 15,  4]])
```

It is my first project with python and numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have repeating numbers, I assume you don't want *all* numbers in the range, but just that the chosen numbers are drawn from that range.

In that case, using [`numpy.random.randint`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) might be what you want.

```
A = numpy.random.randint(-1000,1000,size=(N,N))
```

Comment: if i want to make a bigger matrix like  = numpy.random.randint(-1000,1000,size=(100000,100000)) it shows an error like this   ==== :::::::                                                                                             File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
      a=numpy.random.randint(-1000,10000,size=(100000,100000))
      File "mtrand.pyx", line 892, in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:7051)
MemoryError what should i do ?

Comment: Buy more RAM. A 100000x100000 array of float64 requires 74GB of memory.